# Divide elements from columns with similar prefix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, prefix, divide

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip([1,2],
           [5,6],
           [9,10],
           [13,14])))
df.columns =['x_A', 'y_A', 'x_B', 'y_B']
df:
    x_A y_A x_B y_B
  0 1   5   9   13
  1 2   6   10  14
```

I would like to divide columns with similar prefixes to get the following:

```
df: 
    x    y
 0  1/9  5/13
 1  2/10 6/14
```

Can this be done with a single line if possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Are there always an equal number of columns, and are there always only 2 prefixes to compute (x, y) ?

Comment: Multiple prefixes (x,y,z,w,h...) but they always come in pairs as shown in the example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach:

```
def divide_reduce(x):
    y = x.to_numpy().astype(np.float64)
    return np.divide.reduce(y, axis=1)

res = df.groupby(df.columns.str[0], axis=1).agg(divide_reduce)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
          x         y
0  0.111111  0.384615
1  0.200000  0.428571
```

If you prefer a single line approach, you could use:

```
res = df.astype(np.float64).groupby(df.columns.str[0], axis=1).agg(np.divide.reduce, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the prefixes are always of the format *_A and *_B, you can use `filter` and division to this effect:

```
df.filter(like='_A') / df.filter(like='_B').to_numpy()

        x_A       y_A
0  0.111111  0.384615
1  0.200000  0.428571
```

The second subframe needs the `.to_numpy()` call to force division and avoid NaNs in the result (due to unalignable column indices).